# How to pass variables to other functions inside object in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, object, scope

```
var myCar2 = {

    maxSpeed: 70,
    driver: "Arnold",

    drive: function(speed, time) {
        console.log("speed " + (speed * time));
    },

    logbook: function(a , b) {      
        console.log("max speed " + this.maxSpeed + " " + this.drive(a , b));
    }
};

myCar2.logbook(3 , 6);
```

If I run that code `this.drive(a , b)` is `undefined`. How can i pass variables to `drive()` function using `logbook()`?

Comment: This should work just fine as is. The only thing is that you're ***not returning anything*** from `drive`, so its return value is `undefined`.

Comment: @Amit No. Just no.

Comment: yes i dont use return. Thank you now with return i get what i want.

Answer (score 7):

You are passing variables to drive, and they are defined within it. If they weren't then you wouldn't get *speed 18* in the output, you would get *speed NaN*.

The `undefined` value is the **return** value of `drive`, which is because you haven't put a `return` statement in that function.